# How to change indent width to 2 spaces instead of 4 in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse I have already changed the indent width to be 2 spaces, but my project only indents with 4 spaces. I'm not sure why this happens. 
I have hundreds of lines of code and would like to quickly format all of it to be 2 spaces, so what can I do?

Comment: Change `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit... -> Indentation size = 2`.  And press Ctrl+Shift+F in your editor.

Comment: @saka1029, make this comment an answer and I'll upvote it.  Just let me know when you do it.